# Верстка диаграмы

Tags: html, css

Уважаемое сообщество!

Выручайте. Горю!

Необходимо сделать следующее:

[image]

Делаю так: http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/a3qjm/1/

Не получается.

Comment: А вариант таблицей не подходит?

Comment: @Palmervan, пробовал - не получается ...

Comment: Не получается? О_о

-----------

Жаль у меня нет времени сделать набросок.

Comment: @Palmervan, я не первый день верстаю, - просто ступор какой-то ...

Comment: я бы тоже таблицей сделал..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Может [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/y3R2p/1/) подойдет? На скорую руку, поэтому может туда чего лишнего набросал.

P.S. Или же с [использованием jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/y3R2p/5/)

Comment: @Deonis, огромное спасибо. Век не забуду, - очень выручили.